# Open an email draft via Browser Add-On

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am trying to create a feedback button in my Add-On, which basically opens an email draft with a given subject and email alias.

This is my attempt right now, but clicking the button, does not do anything.
Does anyone spot the problem? :/
I am using Firefox 115.5.0esr (64-bit); and reduced the Add-on to a minimum for troubleshooting.

*manifest.json*

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My Email Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Generate email with a button click",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "Generate Email",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "48": "icon.png"
  }
}
```

*popup.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Email Extension</title>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="generateEmail">Generate Email</button>
</body>
</html>
```

*popup.js*

```
document.getElementById('generateEmail').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var emailUrl = "mailto:feedback@my-email.com";

  chrome.tabs.create({ url: emailUrl });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the answer myself - I used MS Edge to troubleshoot :-)
That's the updated code:

*popup.js*

```
if (typeof browser !== 'undefined') {
  // Firefox
  document.getElementById('generateEmail').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var emailUrl = "mailto:feedback@my-email.com";

    browser.tabs.create({ url: emailUrl });
  });
} else if (typeof chrome !== 'undefined') {
  // Chrome or Edge
  document.getElementById('generateEmail').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var emailUrl = "mailto:feedback@my-email.com";

    chrome.tabs.create({ url: emailUrl });
  });
} else {
  console.error("Browser not recognized.");
}
```